# Undo automatic move to Gmail's categories

Tags: gmail

Gmail now automatically sorts messages into categories in the inbox. I have dragged a message into a category to move it there, and accidentally clicked on "yes" to have all messages with the same email to go to that category.

**How do I undo that?**

[image]

Comment: Drag a message over to the "Primary" tab.

Comment: @AlEverett It's a workaround, but it's not a "cancel do this", it's a "do this other thing". If a message from that sender enters a conversation that would otherwise go to a non-primary tab, now it would wrongly go to the primary tab.

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't create a filter that you can edit. It's either this or turn off the categories altogether.